# Promote InfoPath fields to columns in the form Library using feature

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

I understand that I can do this easily using the infopath designer.However , I need to deploy the infopath form using feature ,once the feature is activated ,the infopath form is shown as contenttype.My questions is how can I promote InfoPath fields to columns in the form Library using code in feature deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still you can do Property Promotion using InfoPath Designer and Deploy the Form using Steps mentioned in the Article.

1. [Property Promotion](http://blog.ksenthil.net/archive/2009/07/25/promoting-properties-e28093-expose-infopath-fields-as-site-columns.aspx)
2. [Deploying InfoPath using Feature](http://blog.ksenthil.net/archive/2009/07/25/deployment-of-infopath-form-e28093-the-right-way.aspx)